# Create popup through JS - Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create an app in JQuery Mobile in which I can dynamically create buttons with popups. I have this code, but whenever I refresh the page, it opens automatically at the top of the screen, unlike all of the other popups.

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#home", function() {
    $(".img-holder").append(
        $("<div />", {"class" : "spot_holder"}).append(
            $("<a />", {
                "href" : "#ashcloud",
                "data-rel" : "popup",
                "class" : "spot ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all",
                "data-transition" : "flip",
                "style" : "top: 35px; left: 240px"
            })
        ).append(
            $("<div />", {
                "data-role" : "popup",
                "id" : "ashcloud"
            }).append(
                $("<p />").text("Ash Cloud")
            ).popup()
        )
    )
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="js/jQueryMobile/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div class="ui-content">
                <div class="img-holder">
                    <img src="img/volcano.jpg" class="image" width="500px">
                    <!--
                    <div class="spot-holder">
                        <a href="#ashcloud" 
                           data-rel="popup" 
                           class="spot ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"
                           data-transition="flip"
                           style="top: 35px; left: 240px;"></a>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="ashcloud">
                            <p>Ash Cloud</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    -->
                    <div class="spot-holder">
                        <a href="#mainpipe" 
                           data-rel="popup" 
                           class="spot ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"
                           data-transition="flip"
                           style="top: 250px; left: 232px;"></a>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="mainpipe">
                            <p>Main Pipe</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spot-holder">
                        <a href="#sidevent" 
                           data-rel="popup"
                           class="spot ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"
                           data-transition="flip"
                           style="top: 180px; left: 210px"></a>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="sidevent">
                            <p>Side Vent</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spot-holder">
                        <a href="#lavaflow" 
                           data-rel="popup" 
                           class="spot ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"
                           data-transition="flip"
                           style="top: 120px; left: 215px"></a>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="lavaflow">
                            <p>Lava Flow</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I have found a solution.
Instead of creating a popup for every button, create a single popup that is chared across all of the buttons, then through JS, change the text in the popup for every time you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create dialogue in pure jQuery way rather than jQuery Mobile.

Below is example how to create jQuery Mobile dialogue. Notice, that there is no Javascript code here. All  you need is to create page with **data-dialog="true"** attribute and link it from your [main] page.

```
   <!--...-->

   <!-- page Help -->
 <div data-role="page" id="help" data-theme="b">
  <!-- header (same data-id for persistent toolbar) -->
  <div data-role="header" data-id="tabnav-header" data-position="fixed"    
     data-theme="b">
     <h1>MyApp</h1>

  </div>
  <!-- content -->
  <div data-role="content" class="content_div">
     <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#about" data-transition="flip">About</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- footer -->
  <div data-role="footer" data-id="tabnav-footer" data-position="fixed">
     <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#home" data-theme="b" style="font-weight: normal;" data-icon="home" data-transition="slide">Home</a></li>

           <li><a href="#help" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" style="font-weight: normal;" data-icon="bars" data-transition="slide">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  <!-- This page is actually a dialogue window -->
  <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="about" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
       <h1>About</h1>
  </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="b">
        MyApp. All rights deserved.
   </div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b"></div>
  </div>
  ...
```

Comment: This is true, however this is not what I want. First of all, I have all four popups working fine with just html, but the problem is creating new ones with javascript (as I want to do this dynamically, as I said in my post). Also, a dialog is not what I want, I want a popup. Thirdly and finally, the documentation says that dialogs are deprecated. I still wish to keep the popup markup, as that worked fine before I added JS, but I want to be able to create that using JS. The markup all works fine when I run it (I checked in F12 menu).

Comment: I don't understand what you means when you says popup. What a difference between dialog and popup? Dialog created by the code provided looks like popup in my opinion, it has smaller canvas and closing control and title. Dialog yes deprecated, but provided code doesn't contains dialog widget. It contains page widget with dialog attribute -- the recommended and up to date way to create dialog windows. Instead of creating dialog dynamically you can try to have one static dialog but dynamically change its title and content.  .

Comment: Look on the JQuery Mobile demos, a dialog appears full screen, this is not what I want. It also navigates to a **different** page, meaning that the old page is closed and not visible. What I want is what the demos show as a popup, where it isn't full screen, or a separate page, just a simple popup that appears on the button.

Comment: I looked. Dialog isn't appears full screen. Background page just grayed or blacked out. But dialog itself is much smaller than whole page. In case you have strong requirement to show background page use popup widget. No need to reinvent bike. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/

Comment: That's fair enough, but the popup is exactly what I was asking about. I can create a popup fine, but I need to be able to create a button with a popup using Javascript dynamically at a certain (user-defined) position.

Comment: There is an example on JQ mobile how to create popup dynamically. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/popup-dynamic/

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on JQ mobile how to create popup dynamically. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/popup-dynamic/

First, they appends on pagecreate event instead of "pageinit". 
Second, and I think this is the trick, they call "trigger("pagecreate")" after append.

```
$.mobile.activePage.append( popup ).trigger( "pagecreate" );
```